# How to add variable to URL?

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to collect data from a website. I have an Excel file containing all the different extensions for the website. F.i. www.example.com/example2. I have a script that succesfully extracts the HTML from the site, but now I want to do it automatically for all the extensions. However, when I say:

```
 siteExtension = "example2" 
 url = ("https://www.example.com/siteExtension")
 r = requests.get(url)
```

instead of:

```
url = ("https://www.example.com/example2")
r = requests.get(url)
```

I get an error code. Do you guys have any suggestions how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to concatenate the value of `siteExtension` to your `url` string. You can do this in a number of ways, but here are the two most common:

```
url = "https://www.example.com/" + siteExtension
```

or, the more ubiquitous form:

```
url = "https://www.example.com/{}".format(siteExtension)
```

Comment: Cool thank you! And what if I want to add two Extensions? Do I just do: +siteExtension1 + siteExtension2?

Answer (score 1):

You're having this error because you're not passing the value of `siteExtension` variable to the `url`, instead you are passing the siteExtension string.

You can fix it as follows:

```
siteExtension = "example2" 
url = ("https://www.example.com/" + siteExtension)
r = requests.get(url)
```

Or using this way:

```
siteExtension = "example2" 
url = ("https://www.example.com/%s" %(siteExtension))
r = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the strings together instead of making `siteExtension` a part of your string literal, like this:

```
siteExtension = "example2" 
url = ("https://www.example.com/" + siteExtension)
r = requests.get(url)
```