# Jinja Expression In Statement

Tags: django, if-statement, expression, ninja

I am wanting to include dynamic variables inside of an if statement.

```
{% elif request.path == "/order/**{{city}}**" %}
```

I have a database I can refer to, to get the city names I need out depending on the url but am having a hard time sending that info in through this if statement.
(Everything works dynamically up until this point)

Solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the views.py

```
city = City.objects.get(city_slug=city_slug)
my_city = "https://www.wesbsite.com/order/{}".format(city)
```

was my solution to including dynamic variables in the url

found at
[How to add variable to URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943549/how-to-add-variable-to-url)

I overcomplicated it but Blye pointed in the right direction, telling me to do so in the views.py as opposed to directly in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Backtrack a bit and just make the condition in the `views.py` then pass a `boolean` in the `context` which saves you the trouble of this complicated notation which contains far too many special symbols to be worth the headache

Comment: Elaborate please, what I'm trying to do here is make a schema that will change automatically depending on the city a visitor selects. Is using request.path a good option? It worked for everything up until this particular point where I don't see an alternative to including the request.path with these dynamic variables.

Comment: The {{city}} refers to one of the values in the context, in this case its 'city'. For the value to be in the context passed to the render() function in views.py you need to get it from somewhere. I suggest instead passing it to the context you create a new variable that could be named myCondition with which you can just write {% elif  myCondition %} so long as you pass it to the context. Its value would be a boolean of the condition you want to check for.

Comment: the point im trying to make is that using strings of paths in templates can be messy and deprives you of the opportunity of using os.join() which helps avoid cross-platform path-string issues so moving the whole buisness to the views,py is a way cleaner option

Comment: Taking the party to the views.py file was the right idea.

Comment: Great, I'd be grateful if you marked my answer as the right one if it helped you so it may assist people sharing your issue